# Finding the causal representation $x_t = 0.8x_{t-1} - 0.15 x_{t-2} + W_t - 0.30 W_{t-1}$

Tags: time-series, arima

I'm having troubles finding the causal representation of the ARMA model $x_t = 0.8x_{t-1} - 0.15 x_{t-2} + W_t - 0.30 W_{t-1}$. I began by removing the redundancy in the model such that 
$\phi(B) = (1-0.5B)(1-0.3B)X_t$ and $\theta(B) = (1-0.3B)W_t$ becomes
$(1-0.5B)X_t = W_t$ but I'm not sure how I should expand it out in terms of $\psi = \phi^{-1}(B) \theta(B) $. Any ideas? Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

$(1- 0.8 B + 0.15 B^2)x_t = (1 - 0.30 B)W_t$
$x_t = (1 - 0.30 B)/(1-0.8B + 0.15B^2) W_t $
$x_t = (1 - 0.30 B)/((1- 0.3B)(1- 0.5B)) W_t$

$x_t = W_t/(1- 0.5B)$

Then, you can use the geometric series formula and obtain

$x_t = \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} 0.5^{i} \times W_{t-i}$